# Git features in Intellij Idea not working

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I have a project that I have to import into Intellij Idea under a subdirectory of the git repo. The git repo is "myProject" and I need to checkout "myProject/projects/". When I do this, I can checkout branches inside Idea, but that is the only VCS functionality that appears to be working. I cannot annotate files or show history.

I've had this issue in Idea 15 Ultimate as well as the new 16 RC. Currently using:

IntelliJ IDEA (Minerva) IU-144.4199.23
Build #IU-144.4199, built on February 19, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_72-b15 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was that I was using a symlink in my path to the git repo. Fixed by going to "File -> Settings -> Version Control" and editing my project root to use the absolute path.

From "/home/user/project/path" to "/mnt/storage/project/path"

Answer (score 1):

Invalidate caches and restart: Sometimes IntelliJ caches can cause issues. Try going to "File" -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart" and choose the appropriate option to invalidate caches and restart IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue IntelliJ git plugin, where I was not able to push changes to my GitHub repo, I came to find out that I was using the wrong credentials for my GitHub account.

Answer (score 0):

my **AppCode**: just Invalidate Caches...

[image]